# How long would it take for dwarves to develop whiskers?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, evolution, fantasy-races

A long time ago a group of [Neanderthals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neanderthal) moved into the mountains (becoming the last major stronghold for them), taking residence in the massive cave systems there. Over time they became shorter, being only 4.2 ft tall on average (to better move around in limited confines of caves). Some of their senses became more keen like better eyesight and the ability to smell poisonous gases. One thing I'm wondering is: could dwarves evolve whiskers, and if so how long would it take?

What i mean by whiskers are cat like whiskers, used for improved sensory awareness.

Note: magic does not exist in my story.

Comment: define whiskers? beards, mustaches, cat like whiskers? Do you mean how long until they evolve hair on their face? becasue humans did not gain hair on the face they lost it.

Comment: I imagine there's no good answer to this question. It could range anywhere between after a few generations and never, depending on if/when the right mutations show up and to what degree there's any selective pressure for whiskers being useful. You can pretty much make up an answer that fits your story.

Comment: You've just asked a poorly received question that someone else then had to edit heavily to give it a shot. Learn from your past experiences. This is the same thing again. This btw can be a random mutation in one generation to the next that proves advantageous or never take place. If you are interested in evolution and biology, start at the beginning. Ask how things work first, that might help you build worlds. Your approach looks to me like trying to build a house by starting with the 2nd floor bathroom

Comment: This query is too opinion based. I almost ***nèver*** vote to close opinion based queries. There are literally an infinite number of potential & equally valid answers for this question. Please review the [tour] and [help] so you can get a better idea how this forum works!